# I am trying to convert one of my columns in my pandas data frame into just alphabet letters, it contains special characters and numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have different strings stored within a column in my data frame. I am trying to remove all instances of characters within each of those strings which are not alphabetic.

'[hello] my name's is Gabe'
output: 'hello my names is Gabe'

The data in the column is stored as following:

```
lyrics_data['lyrics_title', 'lyrics']
```

Here I would like to remove the non-wanted characters from the python strings within the lyrics column in the pandas dataframe.
Apologies for the confusion, this is my first time posting.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there small sample input and expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure what you're asking here because the error seems to have nothing to do with the question. What are you expecting from `lyrical_data[lyrical_data]`? Did you mean to write `lyrical_data['lyrics']`? Please make a [mre], and please include the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Also, `special_chars = special_chars =` is redundant.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to remove non-alpha-numeric characters from strings within a dataframe column?](/q/46241120/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression for the task ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mP6co9/1)):

```py
df["result"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        col1                  result
0  [hello] my name's is Gabe  hello my names is Gabe
```